# Prevent Disposal of View in Ember Router

Tags: templates, ember.js, router, outlet

I want to create an app, where i have a mainContainer and a sideBar, the sidebar and the mainContainer should have routes, without that one of the both clean up the other, when its route is called.

Means if i go to `movies/123`, it should load e.g. a movie in the sidebar, without removing the movie list from the mainContainer and visa-versa.

Right now it doesn't work for me, as the router always wants an absolute state and don't let me decide, what outlet to replace and which not.

Please consider using the new router api (v2) :)

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT

The Router structure looks now like this:

```
 App.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('main', { path: '/' }, function() {

    this.resource('dashboard');
    this.resource('ratings');
    this.resource('movie'); // goes into outlet "sidebar" if i call "/movie/123", it should not remove the views for dashboard or ratings (which go into outlet "content")

  });
});
```

Comment: basically having a normal router with two named outlets
{{outlet main}} and  {{outlet sideBar}}

Comment: This is eminently doable with named outlets and the right route structure. If you posted actual code I could help further.

Comment: i add the router code, be aware that in the Route.extend(..) i put the dashboard/ratings into outlet named: "content" and the sidebar goes into outlet "sidebar"